# Perl - Unable to access Excel File

Tags: perl, excel, cgi, parseexcel

I'm trying to explore Perl and do some sample code. I tried to read excel use Perl. I downloaded **`Spreadsheet-ParseExcel`** and installed in my machine. I tried below code:

Code

```
#!"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe"
use CGI;
use strict;
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

    my $FileName = “C:/excel/Onsite_Report(15).xlsx";
    my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
    my $workbook = $parser->parse($FileName);

    die $parser->error(), ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );

    # Following block is used to Iterate through all worksheets
    # in the workbook and print the worksheet content 

    for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

        # Find out the worksheet ranges
        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
        my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

        for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
            for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

                # Return the cell object at $row and $col
                my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                next unless $cell;

                print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
                print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";

            }
        }
    }
```

and it throws error like this:

```
C:\xampp\cgi-bin>perl perltest3.cgi
Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after ileName = <-- HERE near co
lumn 20 at perltest3.cgi line 6.
```

Please advice.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove the error in your code. That will make my answer look kind of strange, don't you think? And your error and question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unusual double quote character there.

```
my $FileName = “C:/excel/Onsite_Report(15).xlsx";
#              ^------ here
```

Comment: yeah it fix the issue...but it couldn't find the excel file..it throws  **``File not found.`**

Answer (score 1):

Spreadsheet::ParseExcel does not parse xlsx files (unless they are just mis-named xls files). For that, you should use [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=spreadsheet%3a%3axlsx&mode=all). And you might try using the short filename as displayed by "`dir /x`"